# select all data except current month mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I want to get sum of all amounts except the current month. What should I write after WHERE?

```
SELECT SUM(amount) FROM transactions WHERE ...
```

Comment: Hint: use the `MONTH()` and `YEAR()` functions to get the current month and year, and the month/year of the transaction date.

Comment: I have used these functions and I know how to get data for the current month, but I need data from previous months except current.

Comment: Use `!=` to get rows for OTHER months.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do that via  **CURRENT_DATE()** , **MONTH()** **and YEAR()**

```
SELECT SUM(amount) FROM transactions WHERE MONTH(columnName) != MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())
AND YEAR(columnName) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())
```

YEAR should be current

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT SUM(amount) FROM transactions WHERE month != "July";`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/not-equal-to-transact-sql-exclamation?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: What makes you think there's a `month` column? It's probably a `date` column. Also, this will exclude transactions from July of previous years.

Comment: `WHERE MONTH(transaction_date) <> MONTH(CURRENT_DATE)` would be more robust.